# Error al agrupar valores numéricos que se solapan

Tags: r

Intento agrupar filas de una tabla acorde con los valores que tengo en la columna ncbi, en la columna lib y dependiendo si los valores que tengo en las columnas min y max se solapan formarían una única fila siendo el valor mínimo el valor mínimo de la columna min y el máximo el máximo de la columnas max. Este problema lo planteé en un post antiguo de este foro [¿Cómo agrupar valores numéricos que se solapan?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352233/c%c3%b3mo-agrupar-valores-num%c3%a9ricos-que-se-solapan/352509#352509) y se solucionó, el pronlema es que hay algunas situaciones, como la que voy a mostrar a continuación, que no funciona correctamente esta función::

Tengo este dataframe:

```
 dataframe<- read.table(text="ncbi      lib      min    max 
                           NC_002034    PV011   8       911
                           NC_002034    PV011   206     432
                           NC_002034    PV011   287     413
                           NC_002034    PV011   443     631
                           NC_002034    PV011   714     891
                           NC_002034    PV011   813     1123
                           NC_002034    PV011   813     1418
                           NC_002034    PV011   1320    1621
                           NC_002034    PV011   1320    1626
                           NC_002034    PV011   1382    1537
                           NC_002034    PV011   1523    1721
                           NC_002034    PV011   1528    1672
                           NC_002034    PV011   1574    1721
                           NC_002034    PV011   1574    1909
                           NC_002034    PV011   1623    1909
                           NC_002034    PV011   1700    1824
                           NC_002034    PV011   1811    2280
                           NC_002034    PV011   2182    2566
                           NC_002034    PV011   2182    2566
                           NC_002034    PV011   2210    2390
                           NC_002034    PV011   2284    2438
                           NC_002034    PV011   2292    2457
                           NC_002034    PV011   2324    2485
                           NC_002034    PV011   2358    2527
                           NC_002034    PV011   2468    3319
                           NC_002034    PV011   2484    2608
                           NC_002034    PV011   2815    2942
                           NC_002034    PV011   2815    2942
                           NC_002034    PV011   3038    3167
                           NC_002034    PV011   3092    3291
                           NC_002034    PV011   3101    3300
                           NC_002034    PV011   3127    3327
                           NC_002034    PV011   3221    3350", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

y aplicando la función

```
      dataframe<-dataframe %>%
      arrange(lib, sseqid, min, max) %>% 
      mutate(grupo = cumsum(case_when(
      is.na(lag(lib)) ~ 1,    # el primer caso es nuevo grupo
      lib != lag(lib) ~ 1,    # cambió lib, nuevo grupo
      sseqid != lag(sseqid) ~ 1,  # cambió ncbi nuevo grupo
      min > lag(max) ~ 1, 
      TRUE ~ 0                
      ))) %>% 
      group_by(lib, sseqid, grupo) %>% 
      summarise(ssdif = max(max) - min(min));dim(dataframe)
```

Obtengo el siguiente ouput:

```
      lib       sseqid   grupo  ssdif
      PV011 NC_002034     54       903
      PV011 NC_002034     55       188
      PV011 NC_002034     56       2605
      PV011 NC_002034     57       127
      PV011 NC_002034     58       312
```

Como se puede ver el valor mínimo para la columna ncbi NC_002034 y la librería PV011 es 8 y el máximo es 3350 por lo que debería dar el siguiente output:

```
      lib       sseqid      grupo      ssdif
      PV011    NC_002034      54       3332
```

Aplicando el código anterior sin la linea de sumar las lineas veo como agrupa los diferentes grupos:

```
      dataframe<-dataframe %>%
      arrange(lib, sseqid, min, max) %>% 
      mutate(grupo = cumsum(case_when(
      is.na(lag(lib)) ~ 1,    # el primer caso es nuevo grupo
      lib != lag(lib) ~ 1,    # cambió lib, nuevo grupo
      sseqid != lag(sseqid) ~ 1,  # cambió ncbi nuevo grupo
      min > lag(max) ~ 1, 
      TRUE ~ 0                
      ))) %>% 
      group_by(lib, sseqid, grupo)
```

Y aquí el output:

```
                           NC_002034    PV011   8        911    54
                           NC_002034    PV011   206      432    54
                           NC_002034    PV011   287      413    54
                           NC_002034    PV011   443      631    55
                           NC_002034    PV011   714      891    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   813     1123    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   813     1418    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1320    1621    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1320    1626    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1382    1537    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1523    1721    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1528    1672    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1574    1721    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1574    1909    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1623    1909    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1700    1824    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   1811    2280    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2182    2566    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2182    2566    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2210    2390    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2284    2438    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2292    2457    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2324    2485    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2358    2527    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2468    3319    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2484    2608    56
                           NC_002034    PV011   2815    2942    57
                           NC_002034    PV011   2815    2942    57
                           NC_002034    PV011   3038    3167    58
                           NC_002034    PV011   3092    3291    58
                           NC_002034    PV011   3101    3300    58
                           NC_002034    PV011   3127    3327    58
                           NC_002034    PV011   3221    3350    58
```

Por alguna razón está tomandolo como diferentes grupos. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

Creo que toma el valor min y máximo del grupo 1 y lo compara los otros grupos sin cambiar los valores máximos ni mínimos cuando se agrupan

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Adrián, te adelanto el tema, en tu pregunta original, mi respuesta se baso en el supuesto que cada fila se comparaba con la anterior y no con el de varias atrás, que en este ejemplo es claro. Me parece que no es tan complejo, si armamos un acumulado por fila, dejamelo pensar un poco.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. No me expliqué bien en el post anterior. A la espera de tu respuesta. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: No, no te preocupes, fue falta de imaginación mía, era lógico que fuera así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con `cummax(max)` esta función va llevando el mayor `max` que vas teniendo según las filas:

```
dataframe %>%
  arrange(lib, sseqid, min, max) %>% 
  group_by(lib, sseqid) %>%
  mutate(curMax = cummax(max)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(grupo = cumsum(case_when(
           is.na(lag(lib)) ~ 1,    # el primer caso es nuevo grupo
           lib != lag(lib) ~ 1,    # cambió lib, nuevo grupo
           sseqid != lag(sseqid) ~ 1,  # cambió ncbi nuevo grupo
           min > lag(curMax) ~ 1, 
           TRUE ~ 0
           ))) %>%
  group_by(lib, sseqid, grupo) %>% 
  summarise(ssdif = max(max) - min(min))
```

Comment: Perdona Patricio, hay algunos casos como este:                                                   (lib) PV121   (ncbi) NC_001440  (min)1090  (max) 1724  y  (lib) PV121  (ncbi) NC_001440   (min)1763  (max) 2114 Que no se solapan y cuando sigo tu script, este los agrupa en el mismo grupo ¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Lo miro y te digo

Comment: @AdriánP.L., revisa mi última edción, me falto manejar el máximo acumulado por grupo. Cualquier cosa me dices

Comment: Si, ahora si que funciona. Una vez más muchas gracias Patricio